# Which episodes of Fairy Tail season 2 are anime-exclusive?

Tags: fairy-tail

Aside from the *Eclipse Celestial Spirits* arc, what other episodes of Fairy Tail season 2 are anime-exclusive?

Answer (score 0):

All Fairy Tail episodes are listed [here](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Episodes). The background of the air date indicates what type of episode it is, with yellow indicating anime-exclusive episodes.

At the time of writing (The day after [Pi-day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_Day) 2015), the following episodes were anime-exclusive in Fairy Tail season 2:

- All episodes of the **Eclipse Celestial Spirits arc** (204 to 226). Excluding episodes 219, 220, 222 and 226, which were Omake episodes.